# How can I change the color of fillable squares in GNOME Sudoku 3.4.1 on Ubuntu 12.04 to anything less "white"?

Tags: colors, gnome3, gtk

I play Sudoku on my laptop but I find that the white color of the blank squares that we have to fill is hurtful to my eyes. I would like to change the color to something less white, say #777777.

I have tried to edit gtk.css, gtk-widgets.css, and settings.ini in my Ambiance theme to no avail. I assume that Sudoku is gtk3.

I do not know programming but I don't mind editing text files if that will solve my issue. So, if the solution doesn't require editing source code, I'll be grateful for any guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can not change the color with `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`, or any other easy way, as you could in other widgets.  If you need, you must change the source code like this:

```
--- /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gnome_sudoku/number_box.py~        2012-08-14 19:45:16.000000000 +0900
+++ /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gnome_sudoku/number_box.py 2012-08-14 19:41:41.000000000 +0900
@@ -571,7 +571,7 @@
             #    self.style.base[self.state]
             #    )
             #Gdk.cairo_set_source_rgba(
-            cr.set_source_rgb(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
+            cr.set_source_rgb(0.9, 0.9, 0.9)
         cr.rectangle(
             0, 0, w, h,
             )
```

Note that:

- you can control the color with three values representing RGB; the sample diff above is changing `1.0`s to `0.9`s.
- This sample diff is for python 2.7.  If you are using python3 as your default python, change the directory, accordingly.
- If you upgrade your `gnome-sudoku` package, it will revert the change.
- The reason you can not control them with gtk.css is that they are `GtkDrawingArea`s with the custom drawing method and literal rgb value (shown in the above diff).

Hope this helps.